# Unable to install obs-studio Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, obs-studio

The repositories seem to be missing. Anyone any idea how to fix this?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y 
Err:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libsdl2-2.0-0 amd64 2.0.5+dfsg1-2ubuntu3
404  Not Found
Err:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 
libavdevice57 amd64 7:3.2.4-1build2
404  Not Found
Err:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/multiverse amd64 
libfdk-aac1 amd64 0.1.4-2
404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch 
http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/ 
libs/libsdl2/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.5+dfsg1-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb  
404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch 
http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe
/f/ffmpeg/libavdevice57_3.2.4-1build2_amd64.deb  
404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.4-2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with 
--fix-missing?
```

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` recently?  If you haven't, run that then try again.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding. Yes I did, obs needs a custom repo

Comment: What version are you running of Ubuntu?

Comment: @ThomasWard im on 16.04

Comment: ***Are you absolutely sure about that?*** 16.04 is "Xenial", not "Zesty", and you are trying to pull software in from Zesty, which is End of Life, and no longer supported.  Include the full output of `lsb_release -a` as an edit to your question,.

Comment: @ThomasWard It is possible, they could have updated but the process didn't complete successfully.